# Colorbox content not scrolling on mobile safari

Tags: browser, mobile, colorbox

Good Evening,
I created a website using the thickbox where it displays a calendar and one of the problems that has surfaced is the content will not scroll on iPhone type browsers. I have tried to update it to the colorbox and see if that fixed the problem and it did not.

How do I get the mobile browser to allow content to scroll?

Here is a page that I have been using to try and figure the problem out: http://hsr-bsa.org/test/test.php

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Looking at your test site, you appear to have solved this issue. Would you care to share your solution with the rest of us?

Answer (score 7):

With thanks to Jack Moore, the colorbox css file has been updated to address this:

```
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
```

Amending your stylesheet with the webkit specific overflow rule should do the trick. No need to update any javascript function.

Source: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/commit/ca4e63c71cf1ec00fb3340f2e1a0a5512cbc8f0a

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a limitation of the mobile version of Webkit.

[This page](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070702055328223) claims you can work around it by two finger scrolling within regions with overflow:scroll set.  I've not been able to try this out for myself though as I've not managed to get hold of the company ipad to test it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens on this answer question, please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278279/jquery-colorbox-iframe-content-not-scrolling-in-ipad/11361990#11361990) on this very question on another thread. Note that you need to control the iframe contents i.e. on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

This work well for me

```
<script>
    var devicetype = '<?php echo $devicetype; ?>';// get ur divice type variable
    if(devicetype == 'mobile'){
        setTimeout(function () {
            var startY = 0;
            var startX = 0;
            var b = document.body;
            b.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
                startY = event.targetTouches[0].screenY;
                startX = event.targetTouches[0].screenX;
            });
            b.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var posy = event.targetTouches[0].screenY;
                var h = parent.document.getElementById("cboxLoadedContent");
                var sty = h.scrollTop;

                var posx = event.targetTouches[0].screenX;
                var stx = h.scrollLeft;
                h.scrollTop = sty - (posy - startY);
                h.scrollLeft = stx - (posx - startX);
                startY = posy;
                startX = posx;
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
    </script>
```